# SVN: Force svn daemon to run under different user

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

I have a small NAS server (QNAP TS-210) with a limited Linux on-board. I have problems running hooks in my local SVN daemon. If I run them directly, from command-line, all is OK. If SVN try to run them as hook or if they're added to crontab and then CRON tries to run them, both fails.

I was told that this is due to difference between users running these scripts / hooks. I'm logging to my nas via SSH as "admin" and assume that both CRON and SVN are run under "root". Seems that root hasn't got enough privileges for destination folder (I use SVN post-commit-hook to export repository to some local folder) or to run SVN / CRON (SVN also fails on pre-revprop-change hook, even if it contains only `exit 0`, so I assume that SVN can't run hooks at all). Or maybe this is something different?

**EDIT**: How can force SVN to run under "admin" or how can I set enough privileges for "root", so it can run SVN hooks just as I can ("admin")?

**EDIT**: My hook script is in `/share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks` so, calling

```
ls -lh /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks
```

results this:

```
-rwxrwx--x    1 trejder  everyone      147 Jun 24 14:33 post-commit.cron*
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     1.9k Jun 25 12:20 post-commit.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     1.6k Jun 25 12:20 post-lock.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     2.2k Jun 25 12:20 post-revprop-change.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     1.5k Jun 25 12:20 post-unlock.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     3.3k Jun 25 12:20 pre-commit.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     2.4k Jun 25 12:20 pre-lock.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ        6 Jun 25 12:29 pre-revprop-change
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     2.1k Jun 25 12:20 pre-unlock.tmpl
-rw-rw----    1 admin    administ     2.7k Jun 25 12:20 start-commit.tmpl
```

and `ls -lh /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron` gaves me this:

```
-rwxrwx--x    1 trejder  everyone      147 Jun 24 14:33 /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron*
```

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a cron being launched as admin, instead of editing

```
/etc/crontab
```

you should use

```
crontab -e
```

logged in as admin and put whatever command/script you want to be launched by admin with its own crontab. If I'm not wrong, it should launch it as the "admin" user

Comment: No. This is not a pure Linux, only a specific system (QNAP's Network Attached Storage TS-210). Linux on-board it is really limited and sometimes were weird. For example, I'm editing /etc/config/crontab always (other locations of crontab are ignored), being logged in as admin, and must call a specific script to "remember" everything I put there, before restarting crond. Without this, my changes to crontab will be overwritten and forgotten upon next system restart. Weird thing that does not happens on regular Linux (as I suppose) and that is a clear example on how weird Linux I deal with there.

Comment: Inside "my" crontab (/etc/config/crontab) I can also put an "admin" as extra field, to force CRON to run particular job under specific user. But this also doesn't change a thing. Even though script is run by CRON as admin, svn export command inside this script isn't and though is not called up at all. So I need to determine, how to force svn daemon to run under "admin" or how to add it's current user more privileges.

Comment: Just a small notice. If I use `crontab -e`, then I'm editing the very same file -- i.e. the one that is stored on /etc/config/crontab on my NAS device.

Comment: What is the output of : `ps -ef | grep svnserve` ?

Comment: `9134 admin 568 R grep svnserve`. I'm Linux newbie, but I'm getting feeling that this is something wrong.

Comment: Can you do `ps -ef | grep svnserve` again while you are executing a svn log on your working copy ?
If I remember correctly, it should launch svnserve (the svn daemon) automatically (enough time for the svn log to end). And if so, it should be with the ssh user, thus, it should be admin. If I'm wrong, then, no daemon is running, and then you should enable it at boot. But it is strange it wouldn't do it already.

Comment: Sorry for messing around. I forgot that I restarted the server and yet haven't got time to add launch of svnserver to boot. No, I have started svnserve manually and ps/grep gives me this: `7335 admin 964 S   svnserve -d -r /share/Sys/svn' in addition to above. No, I'm really confused. How it is possible that svnserve runs as 'admin' (not root), i.e. the same user I use, and is not able to execute hooks, while I can run them from command-line?

Comment: I just did the same with crond and run into the same confusion. Apparently crond is also run as 'admin' and CRON is also unable to correctly run scripts containing calls to svn or svnadmin, while I can run them from command-line without any problems.

Comment: Did you put a hash bang/shebang in the hook ? (like the first line of the hook script is : #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash )
Is your hook made executable ?
What does `ls -lh /your/hook/script` show ?

Comment: Of course! :) As I wrote (did I? :), script contains four lines -- three system commands, like cd, rm, etc and call to svn export. These three system lines are working fine, is script is executed from command-line or via CRON. Only svn export fails.

Comment: How did you install svn on this nas ? Has it some kind of package manager ? Or did you compile it from source ? Did you put it in the good standard (if your nas linux distribution is following a little bit of standard, though :p) directory : /usr/local
Maybe it is just because cron doesn't have your $PATH set correctly for launching svn . Can you do the `ls -lh /your/hook/script` please ?

Comment: I've installed it using Optware (IPKG), so all I did was to execute `ipkg install svn`. I'm a Linux newbie, how I've got no bloody idea, where SVN went. If $PATH would be the problem, would I be able to run hook/script from command-line without problems? I can't give you full result of your command in comment, so I'll edit question. Look above, please.

Comment: do a `chmod o+r /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron`
It should give the read rights to the other people. Right now, it has only the execute right. So it can execute it, but doesn't know what it can execute since it cannot read it.
The other way is to change the owner from trejder:everyone, to admin:administ with `chown admin:administ /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron`

Comment: `post-commit.cron` is for CRON use only. Real post-commit hook was disabled (because not working). I enabled it (by making a copy of `post-commit.cron`). I tried first approach (`chmod`) and it failed for SVN hook and `post-commit` -- i.e.: again: `post-commit failed (exit code 255)`. Tomorrow I'll write you, if CRON was able to fire `post-commit.cron`. I also tried second approach (`chown`), but use `admin` was already in `administrators` group (no such group like `administ` on my NAS) and attempt of adding user `root` to `administrators` group this way failed (`chown: invalid user`).

Comment: Nope, both CRON and SVN failed to run proper scripts.

Comment: BTW: I'm accepting your answer, though we found no solution, but even so your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `chown admin:administrators` doesn't put admin in the administrators group. It put the user **admin** as the user owner of the script and put **adminisitrators** as the group owner of the script. So that, whe you put the rwxrwx--x you give rwx right to the user, then rwx to the group, then --x to all the other people on the system, which would be the case even for root, so root would be able to execute it, but not reading it would be useless. Since root can change the right, it can give himself the read right if he wants to.

Comment: Can you do a :  
`chown admin:administrators /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron`  
and then a :  
`ls -lh /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron`  
and give the output here.  
Then, try to reexecute the hook by committing something (do you have a stable way to verify if the hook has been executed ?)

Comment: Here is the output: `-rwxrwxr-x    1 admin    administ      147 Jun 24 14:33 /share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron*`. Yes, I have a stable way to verify, if it works. If either CRON or SVN executes whole script (including `svn export`) then destination directory should be filled with current version of repository and for SVN, commit should end up without any problems. Right now, destination directory is empty and each commit ends up with "error with no description (exit code 255)", which I take as that the script was not fully executed.

Comment: It seems that the problem with this lies somewhere else. I did, what you told me to do and it brought no effect. In despair I even set post-commit (for SVN) to 777 and I get the same effect. Once again, I confirmed that I can run manually both "post-commit.cron" (hook/script version prepared for CRON) and "post-commit" (true hook for SVN), and both are executed without any problems (most recent version of repository is exported to destination folder), while both SVN and CRON are failing to run them.

Comment: in cron, instead of launching the script, do a `su - admin` before : `su - admin -c "/share/Sys/svn/tools_and_examples/hooks/post-commit.cron"` It should launch the script as admin with admin environment variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "in cron (...) do (...) before"? My knowledge is limited to editing crontab only, I don't know anything about other issues of CRON. And in crontab I can only use one line (command to be executed periodically) with username before it or not. BTW: I DON'T have "su" on my NAS. Yes, it is a really, really limited version of Linux...

Comment: lol... Ok, I think it could be the reason why cron cannot execute the script as you since it cannot use su.
For this [message](http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=15152), it seems you can get su from the coreutils package. But it seems you cannot have more user. If you have time and you don't use all the bells and whistles of that NAS, install a real linux on it instead of trying to understand a specific castrated linux. It seems somebody created [somewhat of automated installation of debian on it](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/kirkwood/qnap/ts-219/install.html).

Comment: Be warned though, all the administration will be in command line (at first)

Comment: I'm still not sure, if not having a su is the cause for CRON not being able to run SVN export, as it can many more scripts and tools (over 15 entries in my crontab). But, since I'm a newbie to Linux, I can't argue to much, maybe you're right.

Comment: The idea of installing Debian is great, although I would have to learn Linux a lot, as right now most things I do through web-panel and in Debian I'll be completely alone! :] But, have looked at [specs](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/kirkwood/qnap/ts-219/specs.html) of my TS-210? 256 MB of RAM and 800 MHz of processor cause me to doubt, if it can run Debian efficiently? I don't know, if I don't stay with command-line only, as running any GUI will probably kill my "powerful" NAS.

Comment: Forgot to add that a backup of 2,2 TB of data, since Debian installer need to format internal hard disk, is a nightmare even as only vision! :]

Comment: Sure, but as it is a backup,you should have your data elsewhere ;)
The hardware, debian would run just fine depending on the service you will offer.It wouldn't be able to host a big java webapp, but it could host DNS, mail, small blog really easily.And of course file sharing through samba, NFS, ssh/sftp with some web panel to control it.It would be wise not to install a GUI because it would be too RAM eager,and the light desktop wouldn't help you that much since they are pretty geeky too.But yes,knowing nothin at first would be time to spend to learn.For me that time was invested, no regrets.

Comment: Well, I consulted the idea of installing Debian on that machine with a few people, and they all agree, that this is good option, but my knowledge is far to small to be able to actively control such system. So, with regret, but I have to stay with QNAP firmware. Thank you for everything. As final comment, I'll add that it is a bit funny (at least for me) that simple question "How to run svn export as different user" or "how to make svn export work" led us into conclusion of replacing server software and system! :] Thank you and cheers.

Comment: Just one correction. I can use `su` on my NAS, but ends with `su: user root does not exist`. I'm logging through SSH as `admin`, but it seems that this is already a root user.