# Export SVN repository over FTP to a remote server

Tags: linux, svn, command-line, ftp

I'm using following command to export my repository to a local path:

```
svn export --force svn://localhost/repo_name /share/Web/projects/project_name
```

Is there any, quite easy (Linux newbie here) way to do the same over FTP protocol, to export repository to a remote server?

Last parameter of `svn export` AFAIK have to be a local path and AFAIK this command does not support giving paths in form of URLs, like for example:

```
ftp://user:pass@server:path/
```

So, I thing there should be some script hired here to do the job.

I have asked some people about that, and was advised that the easiest way is to export repository to a local path, transfer it to an FTP server and then purge local path. Unfortunately I failed after first step (extract to local path! :) So, the support question is, if it can be done on-the-fly, or really have to be split into two steps: export + ftp transfer?

Someone also advised me to setup local SVN client on remote server and do simple checkout / update from my repository. But this is solution possible only if everything else fails. As I want to extract pure repository structure, without SVN files, which I would get, when go this way.

BTW: I'm using QNAP TS-210, a simple NAS device, with very limited Linux on board. So, many command-line commands as good as GUI are not available to me.

**EDIT**: This is second question in my "chain". Even, if you help me to succeed here, I won't be able to automate this job (as I'm willing to) without your help in question "[SVN: Force svn daemon to run under different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188825/svn-force-svn-daemon-to-run-under-different-user)". Can someone also take a look there, please? Thank you!

Comment: You mention SVN Export as the command you are running... Export takes either the latest head revision or the revision you enter, and sends it to disk... My question: Are you trying to backup the repo, move it or just take the files in it and copy them somewhere else? Depending on which one, SVN Dump would work for both backup and moving, SVNAdmin Hotcopy will also work for both backup and move, and svn export will work if you are just copying files...

Comment: @TiernanO: Third option -- I'm trying to export only files and folders (without SVN meta data) from development server to specified path on customer's production server (customers prefers doing tests on his own machine instead of logging to dev server).

Comment: grand job. will tweak my answer...

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're using Linux, you should be able to mount an ***ftpfs***. I believe there was a module in the Linux kernel for this. Then I think you would also need FUSE.

Basically, if you can mount an ***ftpfs***, you can write your svn export directly to the mounted folder.

Comment: Thanks! But mount is very unstable on my NAS. I've been experimenting with mounting remote Samba share (local network computer running Windows 7) as cifs and smbfs. Both solutions worked fine for a few days and then suddenly stopped to work. Even if ftpfs would work here (I give it a try, if I find some time) I'm pretty concerned, if this is enough stable solution, I've been looking for?

Comment: Well, a better solution by far would be to use ssh instead.

Answer (score 3):

not sure about FTP, but SSH would be a lot easier, and should have better compression. An example of sending your repo over SSH may look like:

> svnadmin dump /path/to/repository |ssh -C username@servername 'svnadmin -q load /path/to/repository/on/server'

URL i found that info was on [Martin Ankerl's site](http://martin.ankerl.com/2006/01/24/svnadmin-dump-and-load-over-ssh/)

[update]

based on the comment from @trejder on the question, to do an export over ssh, my recomendation would be as follows:

svn export to a folder locally, then use the following command:

> cd && tar czv src | ssh example.com 'tar xz'

where src is the folder you exported to, and example.com is the server.

this will take the files in the source folder, tar and gzip them and send them over ssh, then on ssh, extract the files directly to the machine....

Comment: Thanks! Can I exchange "example.com" with "ftp://user:pass@server:path/" -- i.e. provide all necessary info: user, password, server and destination path? Should that work?

Comment: Thanks! Can someone also take a look to "[SVN: Force svn daemon to run under different user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188825/svn-force-svn-daemon-to-run-under-different-user)", please? Without this I can't automate export job, as I'm willing to.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while back - maybe it would be of some use here: [exup](https://github.com/janeklb/exup)