# How to export files from SVN to remote FTP server

Tags: shell, svn, ssh, scripting, ftp

I want to export files from SVN on a server A to folder on a server B, to deploy application.

I am getting specific list of files changed in revision:

```
 r2 | test | 2014-08-26 09:04:23 +0200 (Tue, 26 Aug 2014)
 Changed paths:
 A /trunk/about.jpg
 A /trunk/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
 A /trunk/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
```

saved in file log.txt
I want to transfer all of this files from SVN to remote server over SFTP or FTP.
I have username and password.

Is this possible?
Do I have to write some shell script?

I know that I can export files to some local folder([Export SVN repository over FTP to a remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203566/export-svn-repository-over-ftp-to-a-remote-server)), then transfer it, but it is not effective in terms of storage space, so I would like to do it directly from SVN to remote server directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of files, then strip the 'A' and upload these files ; but I think using a program like [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) would be a better option.

```
rsync --exclude=.svn -r /path/of/repo/ user@remote.server:/path/of/project/
```

Add `--delete` to remove files that are not present on your repository but there on the distant host.

Comment: I understand, that this remote path to repo could not be SVN repo, just a normal directory???

Comment: Yep! Misleading path, sorry. Try it and see for yourself

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it without exporting or checking out to a local file path is to mount a local path that points to that remote server via another protocol (like a local path that points to a WebDAV share, for example). You cannot go directly from SVN to an FTP location.